# modal verb "could" with "when/whenever"

Tags: modal-verbs

1. *Dystopias and You: What **Could** Happen **if** We’re Not Careful*. (http://pezperry.uncadighist.org/dystopias-and-you-what-could-happen-if-were-not-careful/)

Can I replace the "if" with "when/whenever" without changing the sentence's meaning?

2. *Dystopias and You: What **Could** Happen **when** (=whenever) We’re Not Careful.*

Is the following sentence correct?

*Dystopias and You: What **Can** Happen **when** (=whenever) We’re Not Careful.*

Comment: "Whenever" does not work, because it contradicts "could". It is not a synonym of "when". I suggest using matching pairs: "What **can** happen **when** we’re not careful" or "What **could** happen **if** we’re not careful".

Comment: You mean "whenever" doesn't work with either "can" or "could"?

Comment: [**Whenever**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whenever) means "every time" or "any time", which is "always", not "possibly".

Comment: In "What **can** happen **when we’re not careful**" or "What **could** happen **if we’re not careful**", do the when-clause and If-clause **both refer to the future**?